# example of python console output different from print

Tags: python

I would like to have an example of a variable `myvar` that outputs two different things when, on the python interactive console:

`>>> myvar`

versus

`>>> print(myvar)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) gets the [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) while [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) gets the [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), so any object that implements the methods differently will appear different, for example:

```
class Foo:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'STR!'

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'REPR!'
```

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f
REPR!
>>> print(f)
STR!
```

(Just to be clear, this wouldn't be a good repr in practice.)

---

Two real-life examples are [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) and the [NumPy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> d = dt.now()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 10, 13, 44, 25, 491020)
>>> print(d)
2021-10-10 13:44:25.491020
```

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros(5)
>>> a
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> print(a)
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you return `__str__` and `__repr__`, for example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"I'm {self.name}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Name {self.name}>"
```

Returns:

```py
>>> from test import MyClass
>>> myvar = MyClass("John")
>>> myvar
<Name John>
>>> print(myvar)
I'm John
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> myvar = "abc"
>>> myvar
'abc'
>>> print(myvar)
abc
>>>
```

Comment: although they are technically different, I don't think that is what OP meant

Comment: `None` is another trivial example